# Drawing loops around an ellipse in Tikz

Tags: foreach, tikz-pic

I am trying to show the loops of magnetic field flow around a circular current in tikz. I'd like to end with a central ellipse, something like `\draw (0, 0) ellipse (3 and 1)`, that has eight 'equally' spaced rings around it, each centered roughly on its perimeter. It should appear to be a circle with each of these rings equally spaced around it, viewed from an angle. The first thing I was trying to do looks like this: [image: first step]

and the final product should look something like this: [image: final product]

My approach was to use sine / cosine transforms to change the x and y coordinates of each of the rings so that I could just use a `\foreach` loop and automatically adjust the coordinates without having to draw each circle individually. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw (0, 0) ellipse (3 and 1); % central ellipse
        
        \foreach \i in {0,...,7} { % for each of the 8 rings
            \def \x {-3*{cos((pi*\i)/4)}}; % function that returns an appropriate x coordinate for the given i value 
            \def \y {{sin((pi*\i)/4)}}; % ditto for y values
            \draw (\x, \y) circle (0.5); % drawing circles @ (x, y)
        }
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:[image: not what i want]

and throws 2 error codes about missing numbers / units of measurement. This is the lowest amount of errors I could get it to throw.

I have tried different ways and locations of defining the `\x` and `\y` variables, like `\pgfmathsetmacro`, `\edef`, and defining them before / inside the `\foreach` loop, as well as changing the var names in case there was any weird shenanigans with `\x` or `\y` commands, but none of that has worked for me.

Ideally I would also finish with some simple horizontal transformation to squish the horizontal radius of each of these rings to create the impression of perspective, and each loop (including the main ellipse) would have an arrow to indicate direction on it, but this is not as significant.

Please let me know if the description of what I want to end up with is not clear enough.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide a picture of your desired output? Even a hand-drawn sketch would help.

Comment: Of course, added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine, but your use of `\def` is not. Instead use the `evaluate` option for `\foreach`:

```
    \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \x using -3*cos((180*\i)/4), 
        evaluate=\i as \y using sin((180*\i)/4)] in {0,...,7}
```

Note the use of degree measure instead of radians. Then you get close:

[image]

Note that the syntax `circle(2)` is deprecated. You should use `circle[radius=2]` instead. Similarly for the ellipse, use `ellipse[x radius=3, y radius=1]`

To change the eccentricity of the small circles, draw them as ellipses and change the `x radius` with the x coordinate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}       
        \draw (0, 0) ellipse[x radius=3, y radius=1]; % central ellipse        
        \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \x using -3*cos((180*\i)/4), 
            evaluate=\i as \y using sin((180*\i)/4)]
        in {0,...,7} {
            \draw (\x, \y) ellipse [x radius=\x/6, y radius=.5];
        }        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sandy G Well done!+1